# High latency when running a web server in java. bufferedReader.readLine() has 500ms+ runtime

Tags: javascript, java, c#, webserver, java-websocket

So I've been making a server for broadcast control recently however I just ran into some issues with the reading of the lines. When the connect comes in I am creating a new thread and that is where the connection is processed. All the data is supplied within the URL being called. For example:
`/controllerupdate/?_=1597968275949`
or
`/api/`. These return different things from the mixer depending on the URL. The processing for everything else is minimal (<50ms on average).

However, the `String line = br.readLine()` takes up to 700ms to call which is ages when broadcasting.

Here is the block of code:

```java
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String path = "";
        try {
            //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.is));
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.s.getInputStream()));

            long timeIn = System.currentTimeMillis();
            //String request = br.readLine(); // Now you get GET index.html HTTP/1.1
            String line;

            line = in.readLine();

            long t = (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeIn);

            String[] requestParam = line.split(" ");
            path = requestParam[1];

            if(t > 50) {
                System.out.println("T1: " + path + " :: " + t);
            }

            //Rest of the processing code is here
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This code prints out the following:

```
Listening for connection on port 8080 ....
1597968951950 :: T1: /controllerupdate/?_=1597968950775 :: 187
1597968952013 :: T1: /api/ :: 766
1597968953450 :: T1: /controllerupdate/?_=1597968950778 :: 203
1597968953950 :: T1: /api/ :: 453
1597968954950 :: T1: /controllerupdate/?_=1597968950781 :: 203
1597968955950 :: T1: /api/ :: 703
1597968956450 :: T1: /controllerupdate/?_=1597968950784 :: 203
1597968956950 :: T1: /api/ :: 125
1597968957951 :: T1: /controllerupdate/?_=1597968950787 :: 204
1597968958951 :: T1: /api/ :: 345
1597968959450 :: T1: /controllerupdate/?_=1597968950790 :: 203
1597968960950 :: T1: /controllerupdate/?_=1597968950793 :: 203
1597968960950 :: T1: /api/ :: 453
```

The program that does the connecting is a C# program:

Here is the function that does the request and how it is called:

```
        private async Task<String[]> doGetRequestWithError(String url)
        {
            if (!url.StartsWith("http"))
            {
                url = "http://" + url;
            }

            //Console.WriteLine(url);

            try
            {
                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                HttpResponseMessage result = await httpClient.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
               
                String error = result.StatusCode.ToString();

                String content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                return new String[] { content, error };
                
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + url);
            }

            return new string[] { "", "" };
        }
```

Called by:

```
Task<String[]> tsk = this.doGetRequestWithError(this.server + "/mixer?id=" + this.id + "&function=next");
```

Althought the ones that are being slow in that log are from an Ajax call:

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        var xml = this.responseXML;  

                        var inputs = xml.getElementsByTagName("input");
                        var transitions = xml.getElementsByTagName("transition");
                        var numInputs = inputs.length;
                        var numTransition = Math.min(transitions.length, 4);
                        var names = [];
                        var types = [];
                        var isTitle = [];
                        var transNames = [];

                        inputsTmp = inputs;

                        for(var i = 0; i < numInputs; i++){
                            ...
                        }

                        for(var i = 0; i < numTransition; i++){
                            ...
                        }

                        ...
                        
                        $.getScript("http://" + server + "/controllerupdate/?refresh=1");
                        playbackUpdater();
                        window.setInterval(controllerUpdate, 500); 
                        window.setInterval(playbackUpdater, 1000);
                    }
                };
                xhttp.open("GET", "http://" + server + "/api/", true);
                xhttp.send();
```

So with this, I'm just wondering where I am going wrong? I've never had issues with this before!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is `this.s`?

Comment: Assume that `this.s` is some kind of network communication object, the delay in the `readLine()` call is the system **waiting on data to arrive**. It is not an indication that `readLine()` itself is slow.

Comment: You can specify the buffer size with the second argument of the `BufferedReader` constructor. The default size seems to be `8192`.

Comment: Can you show the code for the program that sends the data? What form does the data take? `readLine` returns when it receives a complete line or the stream is closed. If the other side is not sending complete lines, `readLine` will block until the connection is closed

Comment: ```this.s``` is the socket. So ```Socket s``` which is set when the thread is created.

Comment: I have edited the post above to include more info. I looked at the network being slow, but I am not sending that much data. Both computers are connected via ethernet on a gigabit connection.